# Can't install vEstate Real Estate WP Themes

Tags: themes

I have downloaded the [vEstate Real Estate WP Themes](http://themeforest.net/item/vestate-real-estate-wp-theme/5409523).when i try to install it I got this error.[image]
I have update the upload_max_filesize to 20M.plz tell how to fix this error? need quick help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress themes are packaged in a .zip file format (not .rar). Theme Forest packages their items a little differently.

You likely need to decompress the .rar file (double-click on it). Inside will probably be another file called, vestate.zip. Try to upload that instead.

Also, in the future, support for this product should be handled via their designated channel.
http://themeforest.net/item/vestate-real-estate-wp-theme/5409523/support